# Is there a Gitlab CI equivalent of Github Actions?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, github-actions

I'm a bit familiar with the concept of Github Actions -- reusable CI processes that you can "use" in your own CI pipeline on other projects.

Is there a similar concept in Gitlab CI? The idea of putting CI scripts in their own repo, and then referencing that in the `gitlab-ci.yml` for another repo?

I've played around with `curl` api triggers and using the `trigger` keyword in Gitlab to trigger pipelines in remote repos, but they feel like they were intended for a different purpose, since the repos are still largely separate with separate pipelines.

Comment: I'd suggest you look [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/). Especially keywords like `include`, and `extends` should give you an idea of the versatility of gitlab's ci

Answer (score 1):

Oh Yes !! In fact Gitlab has a better way of re-using YAML scripts.
If your goal is to keep common CI templates in separate repo and re-use them from other projects. All you have to do is use `include` keyword.
Read my blog to learn more [Quick Tips for Optimized YAML](https://medium.com/@naweed.rizvi/templates-and-anchors-quick-tips-for-optimized-yaml-541ddafe1d9a)

Answer (score 1):

This project although not per say an exact replacement of Github actions does offer sharable Gitlab CI/CD jobs in addition to the use of `include` and `extend`:
[r2devops](https://r2devops.io/)